# Отправка почты на домен рф

Tags: delphi, email, smtp, indy

Отправляю почту при помощи компонента `TIDSMTP`. Отправляется все замечательно, но когда встречается адрес с кириллицей, типа company@фс-групп.рус получаю ошибку:

> Bad recipient address syntax

Пытался преобразовать в `Punycode`, но получаю ту же ошибку.

Код отправки:

```
zIdMBHTML := TIdMessageBuilderHTML.Create;
try
  zIdmessage := TIDMessage.Create;
  try
    with zIdMBHTML do
    begin
      HtmlCharSet := 'utf-8';
      HtmlContentTransfer := 'quoted-printable';

      zEnc := TEncoding.Unicode;
      HTML.Text := aText;
      FillMessage(zIdmessage);
    end;

    with zIdmessage do
    begin
      Subject := 'Информационное сообщение';
      From.Address := 'information@company.ru';
      Recipients.EMailAddresses := aTo;//адрес преобразованный в Punycode
      ContentType := 'multipart/mixed';
    end;
    zAttachment := TIdAttachmentFile.Create(zIdmessage.MessageParts, aFilePath);
    with zIdSmtp do
    begin
      if not Connected then
      begin
        Connect;
      end;
      Send(zIdmessage);
    end;

  finally
    zIdmessage.Free;
  end;
finally
  zIdMBHTML.Free;
end;
```

Comment: вроде на английской ветке есть ответ: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52133735/how-do-i-send-email-to-addresses-with-non-ascii-characters-in-python https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40132961/java-send-email-to-a-non-ascii-email-address